# Issue with clipboard

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a legacy app I am currently supporting that is having problems when people copy large quantities of data from a datasheet view.

The App is built in MS Access and the amount of rows being copied can get pretty large (sometimes in the thousands).

The funny thing about it is, you can paste the data out, but then Access keeps "rendering" the data into different formats and becomes CPU bound for LONG periods of time.

The Status message beside the progress bar at the bottom right of the MS Access Window is

> Rendering Data to format: Biff5

Biff5 is a "Binary Interchange File Format (BIFF) version 5" According to [Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150447)

The app code doesn't use BIFF5 anywhere so I don't think this is an app problem.

I cannot find any data on this error anywhere on the web so I thought it would be a good question for stackoverflow.

So, can anyone help please?

Comment: What version of Access is this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to copy-paste, can't you just export the query to Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is but sometimes you can run into some very quirky bugs with Access. Have you tried running this on different machines? Different OS's? Would it be possible to paste the data into Excel and then import into Access using import functionality? Can you import the data directly instead of pasting it?

Answer (score 0):

We are all on the same OS here for this, I am investigating the possibility that some update sent out in the last maintenance window has caused this, as it wasn't a problem before this and there have been no new releases of the software in that time period.

Tried in on lot's of machines, same issue on them all.

The problem is actually with copying from a datasheet view in Access and pasting to Excel, not the other way around strangely.

Here is the use case

Access --> "Copy from datasheet"(Normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) --> "paste into Excel" (Normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)
(this works fine!)

When you then go back to Access to continue working, it is CPU bound doing the "Rendering Data to format: " thing, I mentioned above.

I'm stumped to be honest, it's all a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try copy-paste operation through VBA:

Once user has selected data to copy, you can execute the code below when click on a button in the form, and then do a pastespecial in excel:

--- Data selected by user ---

```
RunCommand acCmdCopy

   Dim xlApp As Object  
   Set xlApp = CreateObject(Class:="Excel.Application")

   'New Excel Workbook
   Dim xlWbook As Object   'Excel.Workbook
   Set xlWbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

   'Paste in excel
   xlWSheet.Range("A1").Select
   xlWSheet.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Format:="Biff5"
```